# Terminology in Hudak's Haskell School of Expression

Tags: haskell, terminology

What does it mean '**simple variable**' (marked with red question mark) on page 173 in Hudak's [Haskell SOE](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/) book ?

Could someone please explain what the following sentence means ?

> ... each argument to the constructor -> is required to be a simple
>   variable.

`->` is a type constructor right ? Not a data constructor. Am I correct in that ? 
So the arguments of `->` should be types. This is what I understand but I don't have any 
idea what Hudak means by this sentence.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain Haskell the kinds of "patterns" which can be given instances are very much restricted. In particular, they're supposed to be a single type constructor with some number of *type variables* and each type variable may have its own constraints.

Which is worth stating on its own. Much like expressions, *types* have *type variables* which can be seen as nothing more than fixed-but-unknown variables at the "type level".

The purpose of these restrictions initially was to ensure that typeclass resolution terminated. Since then the value of more complex type class instances has been realized by more sophisticated algorithms for resolving typeclasses and these restrictions have been lifted in many ways.

But to Hudak's credit, I believe he was writing before much of that work had happened. You can see `(->)` as a prefix type constructor much like any other

```
type A a b = a -> b
```

and then interpret Hudak's statement as saying that type class instances can target only things of the following forms

```
instance Foo  A      where
instance Bar (A a)   where
instance Baz (A a b) where
```

and we can now see the meaning of his statement—each type applied to `A` is a "simple (type) variable".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the difference between a simple type variable and a non-simple type variable ? How can a type variable become non-simple ? Could you please give an example for a non-simple type variable ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that terminology. Perhaps that Hudak meant to suggest (based on the context of the box) is that `type` aliases do not count as variables (they are, after all, known) despite feeling kind of like they might.

Comment: These restrictions may seem arduous these days, but note (I think) that by following them, you essentially syntactically forbid all the complicated subtleties that require extensions such as `OverlappingInstances`, `UndecidableInstances` and (shudder) `IncoherentInstances`.  Which may be a reason why no Haskell standard has yet officially lifted them, even if `FlexibleInstances` itself is considered one of the most innocuous GHC extensions.